# How to run services under local service accounts on domain controllers

Tags: windows, service

I changed the user under which the WinRM service runs on one of my DCs. I'm trying to change it back to *Network Service* but as a DC doesn't have local accounts available, the only location I can search for accounts is my domain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Network Service isn't a local account, it's a special principal (it's always S-1-5-20, while a local or domain user account will have a generated authority ID) - it still exists on domain controllers, it's just going to be a bit trickier to find it in the username lookup GUI since you'd normally select it by searching the local computer.

You should be able to use `sc.exe` to set the service back to Network Service.

Comment: It took me some time to get how to use sc.exe to set the service back to Network Service, so I will post it here: `sc.exe config "myServiceName" obj= "NT Authority\NetworkService" type= own`